# How can I avoid a list bullet to appear?

Tags: html, css, header

I am working on a website.  In the header bar, I have included some contact information.

For some reason the first field (name field with my address in it) has a bullet before it.  On Chrome, this displays before the address, on IE and Edge it displays to the left of the main content area in the blue. I cannot figure out how to eliminate this.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample for us? You are likely to get better and quicker help if we see some code.

Comment: I'm not sure what code would help.  Here is the code inserted by the plugin:
 <li id="jsjr_personal_contact_info-3" class="widget-container widget_jsjr_personal_contact_info"><div class="jsjr-pci-contact-section" style="text-align:right" ><h2 class="jsjr-pci-name" style="font-size:12px; margin-bottom:0px" >16637 Fishhawk Blvd, Ste 101, Lithia, FL 33547</h2>

Comment: I have tried setting both ul and li for this class to list-style-type: none; and even added the !important however the bullet still remains.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

for that. `list-style: none` removes all list stylings.

Also maybe check if your markup is valid. maybe there is a missing, closing tag

Comment: Four months ago, the OP said (in a comment) that they tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Yet, it would be a valid solution. Without the source code, it's just guessing anyway what's wrong.

Comment: just saw the comment right now, you're right. anyway maybe his markup is wrecked somewhere which causes the strange behaviour...